# How i can convert a list to a dictionary in python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlrd

How i can convert a list of,

```
>> print(row)
>> [text:'Data 1', text:'Data 27']  # this is list but i want a dic
```

to something like

```
>> print(row)
>> {'text':'Data 1', 'text':'data 27'} # this is how i want my list to be
```

i tried like every possible aswer that i found while googling this.

this is what i got when i write `print(type(row[0]))`

[image]

this is my full code

```
import xlrd

def readData(xlsxfilename):
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(xlsxfilename, on_demand=True)

    # Getting the first sheet in the file which should contain input data
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

    max_nb_row = 0
    max_nb_row = max(max_nb_row, worksheet.nrows)

    # Getting data
    i = 0
    for row in range(max_nb_row):
        if i is not 0:  # skip the first row because it just contains: Data Column 1 Data Column 2
            if row < worksheet.nrows:
                calcScore(worksheet.row(row))
        i += 1


# TODO: calculate the score
def calcScore(row):
    print(type(row[0]))
```

Comment: It does not look like a list, and furthermore in a dictionary a key can occur **only once**.

Comment: I suspect that `row` is actually a string. What does `print(repr(row))` print?

Comment: not its list, this is the output of  print(type(row)) <class 'list'>

Comment: print(repr(row)) is printing this: [text:'Data 1', text:'Data 27']

Comment: That looks like anything but a list... Are you sure that's how you have it?

Comment: Weird. What does `print(type(row[0]))` print?

Comment: print(type(row[0])) is printing this <class 'xlrd.sheet.Cell'>

Comment: Better put a screenshot of what is being printed out, since it doesn't make sense at all

Comment: I did put a screen shot

Comment: Can you post your full code??

Comment: I suspected that the row items were some kind of class instance. So you need to know how to extract the data you want from those `xlrd.sheet.Cell` objects. Is that an Excel spreadsheet cell?

Comment: This question might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909342/python-xlrd-how-to-convert-an-extracted-value

Comment: Yes it's an Excel spreadsheet cell

Comment: please read more about data structures in python

Comment: Yes sir, will do. for now if you could help me that will be great

Comment: You should have mentioned that you were using Excel and xlrd in the question. But anyway, you can probably extract the cell values into a list like `[c.value for c in row]`. But you can't build a dict for the reason Willem mentioned at the start.

Comment: BTW, thanks for responding to all these requests in the comments. But we really _don't_ need that screenshot: the `<class 'xlrd.sheet.Cell'>` text gave us all the info we needed.

Comment: wow, thank @PM2Ring That was all i am looking for :)

Comment: No worries. Next time, try to include all the relevant details in your question. :)

Comment: thanks @PM2Ring some people asked for the screen shot, that's why i post it there

Comment: PM 2Ring, Thanks i will do next time

Answer (score 0):

from the comments, @PM2Ring  suggested using this, and it worked like a charm

`[c.value for c in row]`