# Why this error occurs when I try to plot an array extracted from Excel

Tags: python, matplotlib, xlrd

I have read a range of cells from an Excel spreadsheet using `xlrd` into an array and I want to plot the array on a graph using matplotlib, but I am getting this error message:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

code:

```
import xlrd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('values.xls')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
xvals = worksheet.col_slice(colx=0, start_rowx=11, end_rowx=75)
yvals = worksheet.col_slice(colx=1, start_rowx=11, end_rowx=75)
plt.plot(xvals, yvals)
plt.xlabel('xvals')
plt.ylabel('yvals')
plt.show()
```

I can print the array and see the values, and I have confirmed the type for each value in the array is float.

But when I try to plot the array I get the error message and a blank plot

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what `values.xls` looks like?

Comment: -47.50
-42.50
-37.70
-33.10
-28.30
-23.40
-18.60
-13.70
-8.50
-3.80

Comment: Is that helpful? I don't see a way to attach a picture or a file.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import xlrd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('values.xls')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
xvals = worksheet.col_slice(colx=0, start_rowx=11, end_rowx=75)
yvals = worksheet.col_slice(colx=1, start_rowx=11, end_rowx=75)

xvals = [int(i) for i in xvals ]
xvals = [int(i) for i in yvals ]

plt.plot(xvals, yvals)
plt.xlabel('xvals')
plt.ylabel('yvals')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Returns TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Cell'

Comment: xvals= []
for i in range(first_sheet.nrows):
    xvals.append(first_sheet.row_values(rowx=i,start_colx=0,end_colx=None))

Comment: use that to get around Cell type in the first place.

Comment: xvals= [] for i in range(first_sheet.nrows):
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: xvals= [] 
    for i in range(worksheet.nrows):
        xvals.append(worksheet.row_values(rowx=i,start_colx=0,end_colx=None))

Comment: Gave this:     if key not in self:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909342/python-xlrd-how-to-convert-an-extracted-value

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
worksheet.col_slice
```

to

```
worksheet.col_values
```

and it worked as expected.